# Google SEO - Multi Language by subdomain

Tags: multilingual, internationalization

I've been having this problem for the last 6 months now. I've tried so many ways but just can't figure out a solution.

All the languages settings are in the header

```
<link rel="alternate"  href="https://zh.lovense.com/" hreflang="zh"  />
<link rel="alternate"  href="https://fr.lovense.com/" hreflang="fr"  />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.lovense.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate"  href="https://www.lovense.com/" hreflang="en"  />
```

...

When I search "Lovense" on Google English version, I don't get any problem. However, when I use a French VPN and search "Lovense" on google.fr, I get a Spanish version before the French version (see attached screenshot below)

[image: Google Search Result]

Can someone help me to have a look what caused the issue?

Comment: Well it won't help that all your site titles and descriptions are in English. Look at all the results above you... French... yours English.

Comment: Is site title/description the only problem cause? Any other possible problem causes?

Comment: You should correct those to rule those out.

Comment: Are you including https://es.lovense.com/ in the href lang tags, you didnt mention it?